# Switch on wifiDirect in android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Working on wifi p2p chat in andorid. Now we can switch on wifi of the mobile via code but can we do that with wifi direct?

Cause when wifi is on the code goes in onSucess but since wifi direct is off we donot get any peer list.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the official guides shows how to check it: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Determine if Wifi P2P mode is enabled or not, alert
        // the Activity.
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
               // do your wifi stuff
        } else {
               // warn user to turn on WiFi direct, maybe start an intent to the Wifi settings system screen
        }
```